# Shutdown a device without power button

Tags: samsung, shutdown

My Samsung tablet just fell down and now the power button doesn't work. Is there any other way to shut it down?

Comment: In Settings  do you have Schedule Power On- Off option?

Answer (score 1):

If you have got root acces then install an app from the play store that can shut down your phone. Like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=GRuV.PowerOff.PowerOff

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using Tasker, you can use the `input > long power press` task.